# Postgresql Database Design Questions (Trigger vs Function)

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

I am building a database for a CMS system and I am at a point where I am no longer sure which way to go anymore, noting that all of the business logic is in the database layer (We use PostgreSQL 13 and the application is planned to be a SaaS):

1- The application has folders and documents associated with them, so if we move a folder (Or a group of folders in bulk) from its parent folder to another, then the permissions of the folder as well as the underlying documents must follow the permissions of the new location (An update to a permissions table is sent), is this better enforced via an after statement trigger, or do we need to force all of the code to call a single method to move the folder, documents and update their permissions.

2- Wouldn't make more sense to have an AFTER statement trigger rather than an AFTER row trigger in all cases since they do the same thing, but with statement triggers you can process all affected rows in bulk (Thus done more efficiently) , so if I was to enforce inserting a record in another table if an update or an insert takes place, it will have a similar performance for a a single row, but will be a lot faster if they were 1000 rows in the statement level trigger (Since I can easily do INSERT INTO .. SELECT * FORM new_table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a row level trigger or a statement level trigger with [transition tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-AUDIT-TRANSITION-EXAMPLE), so that you know which rows were affected by the statement. To avoid repetition, the latter might be a better choice.

Rather than modifying permissions whenever you move an object, you could figure out the permissions when you query the table by recursively following the chain of containment. The question here is if you prefer to do the extra work when you modify the data or when you query the data.

Comment: I already used statement level triggers with transition tables.  I already have a view that does the calculation of the permissions, and the only reason I am using the physical tables is my fear of the performance penalty, i.e. I will have hundred of thousands of rows and my thought is that it will be far quicker to have an index scan on a unique index rather than a view that includes multiple tables to bring the permissions together.  Note that the physical table I am using, simply mirrors the data the view has.

Comment: You'll have to run tests to know what performs better.